# Why the change in "Rating" for Batman vs Superman in extended cut?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, content-rating

There appear to be two different versions of the movie Batman vs Superman: Dawn of Justice. The original version was given a "PG-13" rating; a subsequent version was given an "R" rating.

From what I can tell, the second version is ~30min longer than the first version. But, I can't seem to find the the specific content of those ~30min that would warrant a rating change.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The extra footage included some additional scenes of violence, and gore, and some extremely mild nudity. Specifically:

- The aftermath of the African "attack" shows more graphically burned or mutilated bodies, making it more clear why people think Superman did it.
- At one point Bruce Wayne is shown naked from behind.

With MPAA ratings, seconds and minutes can count. A few seconds of violence might only mandate a PG-13 rating but if you add another minute of it, that might push it over into the R. They also take the totality of the movie, and if the new footage makes the tone "more violent" or "darker", then things that they let slide previously might taken on new meaning in context and the whole product becomes R.

As far as I know, the MPAA only ever shares their ratings notes with the studios, so unless WB decides to release those, we'll never more any more details.

Comment: Are those two points a (more or less) comprehensive list?

Comment: not of all the additional footage, no... but much of the extra footage was so innocuous (like more Clark doing stuff, etc) that I couldn't imagine it having an impact on the rating

Comment: That's what I thought. I just wanted to make sure.